# How to reduce duplicative calls to callback functions in componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, firebase, callback, event-handling, react-lifecycle

I am relatively new to React and Firebase. I read several posts about how cumbersome it is to deal with asynchronous functions that return promises or take in callbacks, and there are very few ways I know of for the final output to show “correctly”. I am dealing with many asynchronous methods for my project. From my knowledge, the best place to do async calls as well as put event listeners will be in the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, hence I have a very light constructor, rendering method and attempt to cramp most of my asynchronous calls there as well as put my realtime database listeners there. Currently these are snippets to how I write the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` code.

```
 async componentDidMount() {

    console.log("Component did mount happen");

    const channels_value = await f1();
    const change_object = {};
    change_object[MESSENGER_CHANNELS] = channels_value;



    if (this.state[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID]) {
      const channel_data = await f2();
      const members_value = channel_data["ids"];
      const channel_title_value = channel_data["name"];


      change_object["ids"] = members_value;
      change_object["name"] = channel_title_value;

      //Listener for upcoming messages

      realtime_db.ref(`${MESSAGES_REALTIME_REFERENCE}/${this.state[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID]}`)
        .orderByChild(MESSAGE_CREATE_TIMESTAMP)
        .on("value", (snapshot) => {
          const messages = [];
          snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
            const obj = snap.val();
            obj[MESSAGE_ID] = snap.key;
            messages.push(obj);
          });

          const new_state = {};
          new_state[MESSENGER_MESSAGES] = messages;
          console.log("New state");
          console.log(new_state);
          this.setState(new_state);

        });
    }

    this.setState(change_object);

    //some event listeners that should persist until destroyed
  }



  async componentDidUpdate() {
    //Allows reloading
    console.log("ComponentDidUpdate occurred");

    const change_object = {};

    let boolean_one = false;
    let boolean_two = false;
    let boolean_three = false;


    if (this.state[CHANNEL_ID]) {
      const channel_data = await f2();
      const members_value = channel_data["ids"];
      const channel_title_value = channel_data["name"];



      change_object["ids"] = members_value;
      change_object["name"] = channel_title_value;

      //Listener for upcoming messages

      await realtime_db.ref(`${MESSAGES_REALTIME_REFERENCE}/${this.state[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID]}`)
        .orderByChild(MESSAGE_CREATE_TIMESTAMP)
        .on("value", (snapshot) => {
          //Currently handling all setState logic inside the callback function to output correctly

          const messages = [];
          snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
            const obj = snap.val();
            obj[MESSAGE_ID] = snap.key;
            messages.push(obj);
          });

          //some code for deciding whether to set state
          const deciding_boolean = boolean_three || boolean_one && boolean_two;

          if (deciding_boolean) {
            this.setState(change_object);
          }
        });
    }

  }
```

From some console.logs, whenever I did a `handleSend` that causes `setState`, re-rendering and subsequently causes `componentDidUpdate` to `setState` again, re-render and go to `componentDidUpdate` for the 2nd time and rejecting new updates until this cycle occurs again.

Even though it shows correctly for now, `componentDidUpdate` was hit twice, and I always end up fetching my database queries and callbacks twice, which might give me additional running costs that I’m not aware of. I want to know if there’s generally a better coding practice to reduce this duplication of code as well as cost factors.

Answer (score 0):

if you check at [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) you will see that `componentDidUpdate` has as parameters `prevProps`, `prevState` and `snapshot`.

with that information the most common approach to avoid infinite loops and recalls on `componentDidUpdate` is to compare if `prevState` is different from `this.state` (or some specific piece of state you are monitoring). you also can compare props as well, though it's not your case here.

you can write like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  \\ you can specify which part of state you want to check
  if (prevState === this.state) return
  \\ code to run
}
```

or wrapping the code inside the if statement:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState !== this.state) {
    \\ code to run
  }
}
```